# can't create new User in PHPmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, new-operator

I'm loged in PHPmyadmin with root account but can't create a new user in PHPmyadmin 4.9. It always says "wrong syntax" and user does not exist in db (still trying to generate a new(!) user) ... any ideas?
Cheers, Timo

Answer (score 0):

My mistake ... I used an ' in the password ... screws everything ...